# Why does the resulting matrix from Cholesky decomposition of a covariance matrix when multiplied by its transpose not give back the covariance matrix?

Tags: r, covariance-matrix, multivariate-normal-distribution, matrix-decomposition, cholesky-decomposition

I have a covariance matrix, `S`, which I use Cholesky decomposition to find `A`. [It is stated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Drawing_values_from_the_distribution) that `AA'=S`, however, I am not recovering `S` when I do `AA'`. The example code in R is as follows.

```
S <- matrix(c(1.091385, 1.949606, 1.949606, 4.520746), 2, 2)
A <- chol(S)
T <- t(A)
R <- A %*% T
```

As can be seen, `S` is as follows.

```
1.091385, 1.949606
1.949606, 4.520746
```

But `R` is as follows.

```
4.574082, 1.901370
1.901370, 1.038049
```

And for completeness, `A` is as follows.

```
1.044694, 1.866199
0.000000, 1.018847
```

However, when I do `A'A` with the code `R <- T %*% A`, I do recover `S`.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Or is the [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Drawing_values_from_the_distribution) on Wikipedia wrong? The [R examples](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/chol.html) on Cholesky decomposition seems to suggest `A'A=S`.

Comment: Cholesky decomposition is such that the positive definite matrix $K = LL^T$. $L$ is *lower*-triangular.

Comment: Try what `crossprod(A)` returns.

Comment: `crossprod(A)` returns `S` (the expected answer). So, insofar as the link on Wikipedia, should I use `A` or `A'` as returned by `chol`?

Comment: Cool. Now check what computation `crossprod` is doing.

Comment: The inconvenient truth is that the Cholesky decomposition while usually defined as $K=LL^T$ where $L$ is lower triangular is equally valid as $K=U^TU$ where $U$ is upper triangular. The implementation of Cholesky decomposition in LAPACK (the libraries our computer use to compute Linear Algebra tasks) allow both expressions. R unfortunately has [hard-coded](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/3293d437efa2843ef3a74ad53ca4087d5d4f48b0/src/modules/lapack/Lapack.c) the upper one. (There is a `U` in the call of the routine `dpstrf` that actually compute the Cholesky.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As explained in my comment, the inconvenient truth is that the Cholesky decomposition while usually defined as $K=LL^T$ where $L$ is lower triangular, is equally valid as $K=U^TU$ where $U$ is upper triangular. The implementation of Cholesky decomposition in [LAPACK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAPACK) (the libraries our computer use to compute Linear Algebra tasks) allow both expressions. R unfortunately has [hard-coded](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/3293d437efa2843ef3a74ad53ca4087d5d4f48b0/src/modules/lapack/Lapack.c) the upper one. (There is a `U` in the call of the routine `dpstrf` that actually compute the Cholesky.)

This means one has to transpose the results for `chol` in order to get a lower triangular matrix. After that is done, as you have already discovered yourself, the result follow-up directly. So for example, given the matrix `S` of the original post:

```
U <- chol(S);
L <- t(chol(S));
S -  crossprod(U) # This is equivalent to S- U^T*U and should be approx. 0
S - tcrossprod(L) # This is equivalent to S- L*L^T and should be approx. 0
```

I hope it is therefore clear that the Wikipedia page is not wrong. Being somewhat critical, Wikipedia's [Cholesky decomposition article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) should probably mention that the Cholesky decomposition $K=LL^T$ is equivalent to $K=U^TU$ where $U=L^T$. It was  probably omitted for consistency of notation.

Comment: Can the person who downvoted this post please give some feedback about why they considered this a bad answer?

Answer (score 1):

So, why do you think that chol(S) returns your A and not A'?

In fact it does return A' if you look at the values or read the [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/chol.html). It returns upper triangular, which corresponds to A' in your Wiki reference

Comment: I would say that the Wikipedia article is not clear on whether `A` is upper or lower matrix. Additionally, if `chol` returns `A'` and that matrix is the same as `A'` on the Wikipedia article, then `AA'` should have recovered `S`. The way I'm reading all of this information is that `A'` returned from `chol` is the upper matrix which is `A` in the Wikipedia article.

Comment: Your code `T %*% A` demonstrates my point. You got A' from chol() function, so you need to get A=t(A'), which you called T. That's why you're able to recover R with TA. I understand that it's a bit confusing but when you printed A you could see immediately that it's upper triangle. It would be a little less confusing if you called `U=chol(R)`, then you wouldn't have a weird situation where your A is really A' in the wiki page that you refer to